# Complicated integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

How to solve the following integration g1 with f[z] and g[z] as constant wrt integration-

```
E1 = 0.5

C1 = (x*Exp[-2*x]*(y^(-0.5)*Exp[-2*y]))*
  Exp[-(E1*Exp[-x]*Exp[-y]/(f[z]^2*g[z]))]

g1 = Integrate[C1, {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0, Infinity}]
```

Comment: I’m sure you tried to run that code. What happened? Did it return an error? Did it return the expression unchanged? Did it never stop?

Comment: after a long time , I get this `Integrate[(1/Sqrt[y])*(4*f[z]^4*g[z]^2*
    (-1 + E^(-(1/(E^y*(2*f[z]^2*g[z])))) + EulerGamma - 
     CoshIntegral[1/(E^y*(2*f[z]^2*g[z]))] + Log[1/(E^y*(2*f[z]^2*g[z]))] + 
     SinhIntegral[1/(E^y*(2*f[z]^2*g[z]))])), {y, 0, Infinity}]` which is maybe his question. but seems it's too complex to calculate.

Comment: It shows an error or I should say that actually it goes on running

Comment: What is the meaning of "f[z] and g[z] as constant wrt integration"? Thanks!

Comment: @ProxyKad Does it show an error, or does it continue running? The two are not the same.

Comment: As a general advice, avoid calling "intellectual" functions on input with floating point numbers. In Mathematica, e.g. x^(1/2) is precisely the square root, but x^0.5 is some irrational power very close to 0.5. If Mathematica had some helpful knowledge on special cases involving square roots, but you gave it x^0.5, it would ignore this knowledge and go the hard way, solving (or failing to solve) your problem in the general case of x^a, a≈0.5. That said, unfortunately, even after rationalization I couldn't make Mathematica solve your integral.

Comment: @MarcoB, it goes on running and never stops

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, I mean f[z] and g[z] doesn't depend on x and integration is with respect to x

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that a symbolic solution exists?  My guess is, not.

Answer (score 1):

What about `NIntegrate` (with parameter f2g=f[z]^2 g[z]) :

```
int[f2g_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(x*Exp[-2*x]*(y^(-0.5)*Exp[-2*y]))*Exp[-(E1*Exp[-x]*Exp[-y]/(f2g))], {x, 0, Infinity}, {y, 0,Infinity}]

Plot[int[f2g], {f2g, 0.1, 3}]
```

[image]